# Language of all sequences of permutations whose product is the identity

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Let $\Sigma$ be the set of all permutations in $S_n$. What is the minimum number of states in a DFA accepting the language of all words over $\Sigma$ which multiply to the identity permutation?

For example, if $n=2$, then $\Sigma$ consists of two mappings, the identity mapping $\iota$ and the transposition $\tau$. The language in this case consists of all words containing an even number of $\tau$'s.

Comment: I explained more. Now is it clear?

Comment: This function contains only n! bijective function. right? Now if we need to put it in a DFA, then is minimised DFA also contain n! states??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't stated what happens to the empty word – I'm assuming it's accepted.

It is easy to check that the equivalence classes of the Myhill–Nerode relation correspond to all words multiplying to a certain permutation. Therefore the minimal DFA contains $n!$ states.

If the empty word is not allowed, there are $n!+1$ equivalence classes, one of them consisting only of $\epsilon$.

Comment: what about in case of injective mapping?

Comment: The answer might depend on which direction we're composing the functions. I'm sure you can work it out on your own. Try the case $n=2$ first.

Comment: Can u give some good link for it, I have not seen such concept before

Comment: Neither have I. The problems which are more interesting to solve are those that we haven't seen before.

Comment: We are concluding it with respect to equivalent class. right? and  we are assuming number of states in DFA and equivalence class is same. But is there any possibility that number of states, less than number of permutation , that means that is less than n!  ??

Comment: Myhill–Nerode theory shows that the number of states in the minimal DFA is the same as the number of equivalence classes.